# WooCommerce Select2 Dropdown default sorting filter colors CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-select2

I have been trying to change the colours for the hovered default sorting filter on the woocommerce shop page but I cannot seem to find the selector in Google Chrome developer tools, I can't seem to find the CSS that is controlling the colour of this hover element.

The solution below works for the country selector dropdown only it seems, but it does not change the default sorting hover colour. Does anyone know the correct selector for the default sorting filter selector, please?

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]{
background-color: #FF0000;}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[data-selected=true]{
background-color: #0000FF;}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which theme are you using? Let me know the page URL to debug.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** - Hovered Select2 items get `select2-results__option--highlighted` additional class added by javascript, so use:

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[data-selected=true]{
background-color: #0000FF;}
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[data-selected=true].select2-results__option--highlighted{
background-color: #FF0000;}
```